# Append element in JSobject

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create a JS object which has this structure

```
{ node1: 
  [ 'test1.1',
   'test1.2'],
  node2:
   ['test2.1',
   'test2.2']
}
```

This is my code

```
    for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; i++){
            key = keys[k];
            var result = {};
            var r = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
                r.push(elements[i]);
            }
            result[key] = r;
}
```

the result looks a bit different from my expectation and is not a valid JSON:

```
{ node1: 
   [ 'test1.1',
     'test1.2'] }
{ node2: 
   [ 'test2.1',
     'test2.2' ] }
```

I am not sure what is wrong about the code.

Comment: You are working exclusively with Javascript objects and then talk about JSON. The latter is inspired by the former, but they're not the same. Makes the question confusing.

Comment: But the problem is perhaps that you reset the result to an empty object each time you go through the outer loop.

Comment: Picking up on what RemcoGerlich said: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. :-)

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Add the complete code in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: the first is one object, the second is two objects. Apparently he also prints inside the loop and then doesn't show us that.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich - Ah, thanks! Very subtle.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `var result = {};` outside the `for` loop and it will work as currently a new object is created inside the loop.

```
var result = {};
for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
  key = keys[k];
  var r = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    r.push(elements[i]);
  }
  result[key] = r;
}
```

You also have `i++` in the first loop so change that to `k++` otherwise there will be a infinite loop.

Comment: This certainly starts them off the right way, but we have to know what `keys` and `elements` are. This will just put the same elements in both objects.

Comment: Once they fix that, then if the OP wants to create JSON (since it seems he/she may be printing this out or something), they'd use `JSON.stringify(result)` to create the JSON to output.